# How to construct URL for Google API with query parameters

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, dataform

I'm trying to construct a URL to request with `GET` method:

`https://dataform.googleapis.com/v1beta1/{workspace=projects/*/locations/*/repositories/*/workspaces/*}:readFile`

https://cloud.google.com/dataform/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.repositories.workspaces/readFile#query-parameters

what I have but not working:

`https://dataform.googleapis.com/v1beta1/{workspace=projects/my-project/locations/europe-west4/repositories/my-repo/workspaces/my-workspace}:readFile`

Now I don't know how to put in the `query` parameter `path`.

I've tried to add `;path=my_file%2Ejson` or `?path=my_file%2Ejson` at the end of above URL and `path` is `my_file` at root of `my-repo`

My question is:
Is this even the right way to do this and how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct query syntax for setting the path in your case:

`https://dataform.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/MY_GCP_PROJECT/locations/europe-west4/repositories/REPOSITORY_NAME/workspaces/MY_WORKSPACE:readFile?path=my_file.json`

So it works without the curly brackets and "workspace=".

Comment: Ah okay, I did try without curly brackets but left the ```workspace=``` in. The docs could be better